# Entity Framework Core: detach Included entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an entity and want to update the included entities, however, since they are tracked, and I am using an AutoMapper, I get an error saying as much.

The issues is if I untrack the entity:

```
// Find the Contact
Contact? contact = await repository
    .Entity()
    .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution() // Or AsNoTracking()
    .Include(c => c.Roles)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == contactDto.Id, cancellationToken);
```

I still get the error since the `Role` entity in `Roles` is still tracked. How do I both include and untrack them. My ultimate goal is to exchange the `Roles` from the `ContactDto` to the `Contact`.

Comment: This and your previous question sound like XY problem. `ContactDto` should contain collection of `RoleDto`, not `Role` entity. It should have trivial mapping during the read (with both AM `Map` or `ProjectTo`), and AutoMapper.Collection package (for EF Core) could help applying disconnected dto changes. If not, then you should do that manually with a *proper* control of the change tracking when mapping collection of `RoleDto` to collection of `Role`.

Comment: This also means that `repository` has a context instance that already tracks these roles, which probably means that you do too much with one `repository` instance. I.e. you seem to have a context life-cycle problem, which may be another "X" preceding this "Y".